# Sensitive Data in Vue Data Property

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, security

I've been learning Vue for the past month or so but one question still eludes me:

The web app I'm building allows users to collect daily diaries for various projects, so they can switch from one project to another an edit the relevant diaries.

With role based authentication in mind (not implemented yet) I plan to load the first project the user has access to as the entry point to the app. I'd do this by fetching the first project they have access to from the API and store it as a data property in App.vue like so:

```
  data: ({
    appState: {
      projectCode: "1298BAX",
      projectName: "Learning JavaScript 2020",
      availableProjects: ["Learn Node", "Learn Express"],
      company: [],
    },
  }),
```

The 'appState' object dictates which diaries the app should load by referencing the 'projectCode' property when fetching diaries from the API. And if the user switched to a different project e.g. "Learn Node" then the new appState would be:

```
  data: ({
    appState: {
      projectCode: "444444",
      projectName: "Learn Node",
      availableProjects: ["Learning JavaScript 2020", "Learn Express"],
      company: [],
    },
  }),
```

Now the user can fetch the "Learn Node" diaries when they navigate to the list of diaries they can edit.

**My concern is that, this isn't a secure pattern. Is storing such data which will be used in API calls safe in the data property? Would this be a security issue or is it typically safe to do it this way?**

I welcome your constructive feedback and suggestions. I apologise for my ignorance but as a solo dev learning without an experienced dev, theoretical questions like this are hard to solve when Googling lets you down :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No data is safe once its in the browser. Only solution is to always check user privileges on the server side...

Don't trust anything coming from the browser :)

Comment: Would you say in this case. Whenever I use the Project Code in the API call just make sure the user is authenticated before accepting the request?

Comment: Yes. When you are fetching diaries from server, server should always check that user is authenticated and has access to requested project...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Vue question so everything I say here applies to anywhere else on the web. When it comes to securing your website take this simple rule and run with this:

**Nothing in the front-end it secured.**

And I mean nothing. Even if you put Auth Guards on it, and more stuff like that, if the information is stored inside JavaScript files, they are available for anyone to see.

The only way to truly secure something is by having the server serve it to the client. The serve code is not visible to the client, that's why you can do whatever you want there.

You do want to implement a system of authentication though, I recommend using  a ready system like Auth0, JWT Tokens, or Firebase and not setting this up completely from scratch on your own.

In essence the reason why it's secure when using these systems is that each user has a unique ID that can't be guessed by anyone, or a unique token, and when the user makes the request to the server with the ID/Token only then the user can access sensitive information from the data-base, and only where this user's specific information is stored.

So if user x can only get the information that's associated with user x and user y can only get the information that's associated to him.

If anyone tries to make an API call and get some information, he will only be able to get his own information, never someone else's because the authentication and ID/Token comparison happens in the backend and like I said, trying to guess the unique UID is virtually impossible because it's so unique. (Also a lot of systems will block attempts to fake it)